# How to save to current text file/update to current text file?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I currently have a program that allows you to add a new student, or save new information about a current student. I'm new to BufferedReader/Writer, FileWriter and I just used it in this one lab. Right now when I add the new student it adds the data into a new text file, and deletes the current array of students. If anyone can help that would be great.

```
try 
     {
        if((nameBox.getText().equals("")) || (ageBox.getText().equals("")) || (weightBox.getText().equals(""))|| (allBox.getText().equals("")))
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please input Data!", "Data?", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        else 
        {
           studentArray[t] = new Student();
           studentArray[t].changeName(nameBox.getText()) ;
           studentArray[t].changeAge(Integer.parseInt(ageBox.getText()));
           studentArray[t].changeWeight(Double.parseDouble(weightBox.getText()));
           studentArray[t].changeAllergy(Boolean.parseBoolean(allBox.getText()));
           count++;

           System.out.println("" + studentArray[t].getName());
           System.out.println("" + studentArray[t].getAge());
           System.out.println("" + studentArray[t].getWeight());
           System.out.println("" + studentArray[t].getAllergy());
           System.out.println("" );
        }

        //FileWriter files = new FileWriter(file);
        //BufferedWriter pies = new BufferedWriter(files);

        //String data = studentArray[t].getName() + "%" + studentArray[t].getAge()+"%" + studentArray[t].getWeight()+ "%" + studentArray[t].getAllergy();
        //pies.write(data);

        //pies.close(); 

     }

     catch(Exception z)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong type!", "Type?", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);          
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `ArrayList` instead of an Array. So you can just add a new Student:

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList();
```

Then, instead of iterating over your Array, just create a new Student object.

```
Student student = new Student();
student.changeName(nameBox.getText()) ;
student.changeAge(Integer.parseInt(ageBox.getText()));
student.changeWeight(Double.parseDouble(weightBox.getText()));
student.changeAllergy(Boolean.parseBoolean(allBox.getText()));
```

And now you add it to your studentList:

```
studentList.add(student);
```

And if you've added all the students you wanted, you can **append** the studentList to your file. It's important to add `true` as operator to your `FileWriter` because that way it appends the input:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true); 
  for(Student st: studentList) {
    String data = st.getName() + "%" + st.getAge()+"%" + st.getWeight()+ "%" + st.getAllergy();
    writer.write(data+"\n");
}
writer.close();
```

So here you iterate over your `studentList` and append it to your file. You see the `\n`? That is a line break and it means, that one student has one line.

Comment: I've written that without actually being able to test it(text editor only). If there is something unclear or wrong, feel free to ask.